# Filter JSON document in Python keeping original key path structure

Tags: python, json, filter, nested, jmespath

I'd like to know if there is an existing Python library for filtering JSON documents by full key path that preserves the document's original structure. Here's an example:

Inputs

```
d = {"a": {"b": "c", "d": "e"}, "f": [{0: 0}, {1: 1}]}
keyPaths = ["a.b", "f[1]"]
```

Desired Output

```
{"a": {"b": "c"}, "f": [{1: 1}]}
```

The closest solution I have found is the [jmespath MultiSelect Hash](http://jmespath.org/specification.html?highlight=preserve%20structure#multiselect-hash) operation; however, I don't think it can create the full hierarchy. For instance:

`jmespath.search("{a: a.b, f: f[1]}", d)` yields `{'a': 'c', 'f': {1: 1}}`

But it doesn't allow `a.b` as a keyval-expr's identifier i.e., `{a.b: a.b}` is invalid. One solution would be to use the MultiSelect Hash along with code to generate the missing structure for each key path. I'm wondering though if there's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use this expression

```
{"a":{"b":a.b}, "f":f[1]}
```

for input:

```
{"a": {"b": "c", "d": "e"}, "f": [{0: 0}, {1: 1}]}
```

to get output:

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": "c"
  },
  "f": {
    "1": 1
  }
}
```